# Why does Url.Action("ActionName") produce an argument at the end of the generated URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url, view

In a partial view, I use `Url.Action` to generate a URL for an action like below:

```
<form id="MyForm" action="<%= Url.Action("Edit") %>">
```

I was expecting it generates `/MyController/Edit` for me, but it instead generates `/MyController/Edit/123`, where `123` is an ID. That was the URL that was called to render this partial view.

My question is, how come it generated the URL that rendered the page, instead of the URL I was expecting? How can I generate the URL I expect, i.e. `/MyController/Edit`?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have 2 actions that accept get requests with the name Edit on that controller?  i'm not sure, but i can see it getting confused, especially with the default route being /controller/action/id

Comment: Yes, I do. One is `Edit(id)` for `GET`, and the other is `Edit(Model)` for `POST`.

Comment: @William, the current `Model` is passed in when you use the `Action()` overload you use, and it has `123` for `id`. Cf. what @nathan says.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475981/ambient-values-in-mvc2-net-routing) i asked a while ago. There you can find some detail discussion on the issue that previous values are retained in some scenarios when matching routes

Comment: this is a bit annoying that this problem is not resolved yet... :(

Comment: yep, not even in mvc-3. look at khalid's answer it looks promising but haven't tried yet