# asp.net mvc - inconsistent rendering of ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller which accepts URLs in the following two formats:

- **Network/AddOrEdit** -> renders a blank form on a page to add a new network object
- **Network/AddOrEdit/[id]** -> renders a page with prepopulated form to edit the network object
  with ID [id]

Obviously it's the same view being used in each instance - one of my design goals is to use the same view for adding and editing purposes.

The master page contains a link to the add page like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddOrEdit", "Network")
```

Ordinarily this renders correctly as `/Network/AddOrEdit`.

However, when I am on the edit page (i.e. the current URL is in the format `Network/AddOrEdit/[id]`), then the Add link renders with that ID on the end - so the add link actually points to the edit page. This is not what I want!

So for some reason MVC seems to be allowing the current ID from the query string to interfere with the rendering of the ActionLink.

Any suggestions what I can do about this? :(

Comment: I think this question has been asked before on SO:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780643/asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink-keeping-route-value-i-dont-want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guessing is right. MVC routing mechanism may reuse route variables from the current request to generate outgoing route data. That's why the `id` parameter is populated from the current request. You should explicitely specify `id` when generating link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddOrEdit", "Network", new { id = String.Empty }, null)
```

And when routing system sees route with optional `id` parameter, and route value with `string.Empty`, it generates link without `id` in the end

Comment: This solved the problem. Guess I just don't know my ActionLink overloads well enough!

Answer (score 2):

Tried this myself:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddOrEdit", "Network", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional })
```

Apparently, this one works too.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddOrEdit", "Network", new { id = String.Empty })
```

Hopefully this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you've understood the question. I want the link to render WITHOUT an ID on the end.

Comment: Thanks for coming back on this Daryl, but this didn't work. Bizarrely, it just appended the text 'Length=7' onto the end of the query string.

Comment: One of those all-important nulls.