# MVC 3 Routing - Single Action Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a question about routing / navigation with-in the same controller.

Lets say I've got the following route setup

```
routes.MapLowercaseRoute("SomeAwesomeControllerLookup",
    "SomeAwesomeController/{genre}/{region}/{lookup}",
    new
    {
        controller = "SomeAwesomeController",
        action = "Index",
        genre = UrlParameter.Optional,
        region = UrlParameter.Optional,
        lookup = UrlParameter.Optional,
});
```

And a Url Action as follows

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeAwesomeController", new { genre = "Movies" })">Movies</a>
```

I would expect my URL's to look like "/someawesomecontroller/movies" every time however when I've navigated to a filtered URL like "/someawesomecontroller/movies/boston/today" my menu URL's remain "/someawesomecontroller/movies/boston/today" regardless of the parameters specified in the HTML snipped above.

I can ensure the URL rendered is always "/someawesomecontroller/movies" without hard-coding it?

Answer (score 0):

As I learnt some other time, the route values are filtered down and used by the Action renderer.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeAwesomeController", new { genre = "Movies", region="", lookup="" })">Movies</a>
```

Should fix your problem. (Could also try "null", but I believe that won't override the existing route values.

Comment: Not entirely it seemed to transform the parameters into query string values  
ex: /someawesomecontroller/movies?region=blah&lookup=blah  

I also tried the following  
  
`<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeAwesomeController", new { genre = "Movies", region=UrlParameter.Optional, lookup=UrlParameter.Optional })">Movies</a>`
  
But that just emptied the query string parameters. ex:  
/someawesomecontroller/movies?region=&lookup=  
  
Unfortunately one can't assign null to a anonymous parameter.

Comment: @BarendB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513933/asp-net-mvc-inconsistent-rendering-of-actionlink/7513960#comment9102664_7513960 try this link. That's where I remembered it.