# MVC 3 Route - Add old url parameter to new one automatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have two MapRoute in global asax.`

```
            routes.MapRoute(
           "AutoGeneratedURLHandler", // Route name
           "{modulepath}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );      



        //default route
        routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Account", action = "Logon", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );`
```

And I have two link on masterpage.

```
  <li><%:Html.ActionLink("Card Types", "Index", "CardType", new { modulepath="CardManagement" },null)%></li>
                 <li><%:Html.ActionLink("Home Page", "Index", "Home")%></li>
```

After I click Card Types link,  Home Page link becomes "/CardManagement/Home/Index" instead of "/Home/Index".

Route values remember "modulepath" and add it auto to home page link. But I dont want this. How can I make it not add module path to url?

Comment: When I use `Html.RouteLink` and `RedirectToRoute` instead of `Html.ActionLink` and `RedirectToAction`, it works as expected. But is not there another solution?  Should not I use `Html.ActionLink` and `RedirectToAction` in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ActionLink`, you could use a `RouteLink` and send it down your default route. Another option is to not use the ActionLink helper and just roll the link on your own:

```
<a href="home/index">Home</a>
```

Comment: Should not I use Html.ActionLink and RedirectToAction in the project? If I use these two, I will have this problem. Is not there a solution for `ActionLink` ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780643/asp-net-mvc-html-actionlink-keeping-route-value-i-dont-want/780812#780812

Comment: Not the "new id" part but his explanation of how the URL is derived.